# Trying to return data from 2 tables in JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am querying a members table to return all the data in that table, I also have another table that holds members interest and its linked to the members table by the member id. I want to return JSON so the members interest show as an array under the main members object data.

This is what I am getting out

http://www.dile.ng/member/model/getAllMem.php

I will rather just get the interest which shows at the top as seperate objects show as an interest array under each member object

```
require_once("../functions.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM members";
$res=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $id=$row['member_id'];
    $sqla="SELECT interest FROM memint WHERE  memid='$id'";
$resa=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqla);
  while($rowa=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resa))
{
    $data[]=$rowa;
}
   $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge the `interest` values into the `member` object, you need to create a separate array for them and then add that as a field to the `member` object. Something like this should work:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM members";
$res=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $id=$row['member_id'];
    $sqla="SELECT interest FROM memint WHERE  memid='$id'";
    $resa=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqla);
    $interests = array();
    while($rowa=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resa)) {
        $interests[] = $rowa['interest'];
    }
    $data[] = array_merge($row, array('interests' => $interests));
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The database should be able to do much of the work for you using [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```
$sql = "SELECT members.*, JSON_ARRAYAGG(interest) AS interests FROM 
        members  
        INNER JOIN memint on members.member_id=memint.memid
        GROUP BY members.member_id";

$res=mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);

$data = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { $data[] = $row; }

echo json_encode($data);
```

(disclaimer: I don't use MySQL, but theoretically this should work)

—-

#### Edit:

I may have a bad assumption here: the value for `interests` column will probably be a json **string**, not a php array. Therefore when assigning it to `$data` you would need to decode it in order for the later encode to work.

It would look more like

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    $row[‘interests’] = json_decode($row[‘interests’];
    $data[] = $row; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, I truely appreciate it. I went with Nick's approach because I don't like using too much SQL, it worked just as expected.